# Can't start sessions in chrooted nginx php-fpm environment in FreeBSD

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, chroot, session

I have a FreeBSD 11 machine running latest Nginx and PHP-FPM in chrooted mode.
Everything worked fine, until I added `start_session();` to `index.php`.

This is when I received the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Cannot open source device in /index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /index.php(5): session_start() #1 {main} Next Exception: Cannot open source device in /index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /index.php(5): session_start() #1 {main} Next Exception: Cannot open source device in /index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /index.php(5): session_start() #1 {main} Next Exception: Cannot open source device in /index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /index.php(5): session_start() #1 {main} Next Error: Failed to create session ID: files (path: /home/project/customers/john/tmp) in /index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /index.php(5): session_start() #1 {main} thrown in /index.php on line 5
```

Please advice.

```
nginx.conf
    server {
        listen      443 ssl http2;

        add_header  Cache-Control no-cache;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /home/project/ssl/project.chain;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/project/ssl/project.key;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        server_name     john.project.net;
        error_log       /home/project/logs/john-error.log;
        access_log      /home/project/logs/john-access.log;

        root            /home/project/customers/john;
        index           index.php;

        location / { deny all; }

        location = / { }
        location = /index.php {
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm-project-john.sock;
            try_files       $uri =404;
        }
        location ~ \.(txt|css|map|jpg|png|gif|ico|htc|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|js|ogg)$ { }
    }

php-fpm.conf
    [project-john]
    prefix = /home/project/customers/john
    user = www
    group = www
    listen = /var/run/php-fpm-project-john.sock
    listen.owner = www
    listen.group = www
    listen.mode = 0660
    pm = dynamic
    pm.max_children = 5
    pm.start_servers = 2
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1
    pm.max_spare_servers = 3
    chroot = $prefix
    chdir = /
    php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /home/project/customers/john/tmp ; Writable

index.php
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    echo "test";
    session_start();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP sessions rely on `/dev/urandom` by default to generate the random id, which is of course not accessible in PHP-FPM chrooted mode. There are hundreds of other OS dependencies, which my projects needs to function correctly.

At this point I'm dropping any possible chance of using PHP-FPM's chrooted mode.

But if someone is still interested, you need to mount:
`/dev/urandom` to `/home/project/customers/john/dev/urandom`.

https://www.vennedey.net/resources/3-Secure-webspaces-with-NGINX-PHP-FPM-chroots-and-Lets-Encrypt

Answer (score 1):

Your `php_admin_value[session.save_path]` must be relative to the chroot path.  (After the chroot, it will just need to appear as `/tmp`).  Right now it's looking for that value within the process root, which results in it looking for a "real path" of `/home/project/customers/john/home/project/customers/john/tmp`, which is unlikely to exist.

Comment: It's actually not that, there is a different error for non-existent path for sessions. The issue was `/dev/urandom` not being accessible.